# Routing all traffic via home network on hardware level

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, routing

I have a laptop on which I cannot install any software and modify network settings. My goal is to make it look like I am connected to the internet from home while in reality I am somewhere else. My router from ISP doesn't allow to install VPN, I haven't checked if my public IP is static but I would assume it is not. I have a rather flexible budget and I am happy to purchase 2 extra routers/points of access. My understanding would be that I buy one router on which I install VPN and connect it by wire to my ISP router at home. I also buy another router which I carry with me during my travels. My laptop will be connected to that 'travel' router which will in turn be connected to the network at my travel location and will wire all traffic via my home network.
Does that method sound plausible/ reasonable? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solutions working on the hardware lvl.

How do I make this thing work? :)

P.S. I have >1gbit/s up/down at home.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To piggy-back on @davidgo's answer, don't buy a router based on its OEM firmware, instead buy one that's OpenWrt/DD-WRT compatible _(both are opensource router firmwares)_, as it's the only way to ensure routers remain up-to-date and allows the most control/flexibility with one's router _(OEMs only support routers for 1 - 2yrs before they're considered EoL [End of Life] and updates stop)_. WireGuard or OpenVPN would be the #1 and #2 VPNs for throughput.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ If choosing to go with opensource firmware, it's recommended to invest in a FTDI [USB-TTL cable](https://ftdichip.com/product-category/products/cables/usb-ttl-serial-cable-series/) _(allows access to the router's bootloader for recovery flashing in the event a flash goes wrong or direct access to the OS via a serial connection if SSH fails for some reason)_. I prefer a USB-TTL AJ [Audio Jack] cable, but this involves the extra step of installing a 3-prong 3.5mm audio jack in the router's casing & soldering wires from each lead to a header connector for the router's serial header

Comment: I removed the hardware recommendation request in an effort to stop the question being closed.

Comment: Your edit creates more questions before we can answer - what type of connection do you have (ethernet?) what is the maximum speed of connection - (if ethernet do you need more then 1 gigabit), can you replace your "ISP router"?  Does your ISP router allow port mapping?   Is said router controlled by the entity that has locked access to your home network?  Its quite important you establish if you have a static IP address or what mechanism is used to identify your home network before we can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds plausible, although we would need to know a lot more about your setup to be sure the best way to do it.

You will want to ensure your routers are very flexible & can handle Openvpn - I'd get get dd-wrt devices.  Worst case you might land up setting the VPN up using the less common TAP mode, which converts your vpn into a virtual bridge/switch (and not actually using the routing functionality of the routers).  You need to be aware that this mode is less efficient then the standard tun mode, but it presents to the network as if its a network cable - so other then speed/latency it can be indistinguishable.

You will likely want to get a static for your home router - it will make your life easier and guarantee you dont have problems with carrier grade NAT.

Comment: General FYI: OpenWrt is another great opensource router firmware option _(it appears DD-WRT finally supports more devices and has updated it's documents section, as previously both were lacking when compared to OpenWrt, even though DD-WRT is just as old as OpenWrt - DD-WRT's package repo appears to have significantly grown or at least it previously wasn't easy to find due to poor site linking/documentation)_

Comment: Good to know. LastvI looked - maybe 10 years ago - openwrt did not include a GUI by default and was harder to get working (I dod use it, but for non-linux people a very steep learning curve.  DD-wrt was not quote as well supportrd but easier to use). There was/is also Tomato.  DD-wrt was maybe also ahead of the others as iirc it was the basis for asuswrt.

Comment: For a really long time, DD-WRT stagnated until quite recently, as their docs section and site navigation was horrendous _(e.g. prior to today, I last looked at their site ~2yrs ago, and I was unable to find a link to a package repo, their docs hadn't been updated since the early 2010s and lacked in content, and their supported devices were still mainly Netgear)_. After looking at their site this morning, all of that's changed and they're on par with OpenWrt in all the above. If using a Netgear device, DD-WRT will always be the place to go as that's the one OEM OpenWrt doesn't support well.